# Devexpress winforms -using the "ErrorText" on textEdit removes background image

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I am using Devexpress  with Winforms

i am using validating event to check my input, 
but when i try using the "ErrorText" (on wrong input)
the error icon appears but the also removes background image from my textEdit component-  when the user retype the background image returns as normal.

how can i avoid the background from changing?

Comment: Devexpress technical support are really good in my experience so they are best placed to help you and will normally give you a code example